# Get 'My Documents' path in windows using php

Tags: php, windows-8, windows-7

I want to create temp files inside users 'My Documents' folder using php.
Is there any inbuilt function available in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
<?php echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just assume you're running PHP locally on the users PC...

You can get the user profile folder via the $_SERVER superglobal:

```
$_SERVER['USERPROFILE']
```

Appending `Documents` to this should point to the default path.  Running the following at the command line:

```
php -r "echo $_SERVER['USERPROFILE'] . '\Documents';"
```

gives:

```
C:\users\<username>\Documents
```

**Note:** It's possible to move the location of the documents folder so this is not a bullet-proof method.

Comment: I am using phpdesktop executable package. It says 'USERPROFILE' is undefined index.

Comment: I suggest you post in the [PHP Desktop Forum](https://groups.google.com/group/phpdesktop) about this.